# Radio Button Value Submitted As ON instead of Value

Tags: mysql, input, radio-button

I'm a dev noob.

I recently got MySQL to at least start building a database thanks to the help I have recieved here! Woot.

I am aware that I am prone to injections and I'm using deprecated MYSQL but right now I just want to get my radio value to display as male or female in my DB before I deal with sanitization. Right now it gets into the DB as "On" regardless of which gender is checked.  I have looked at a lot of other threads on SO but the code was abridged so I thought I'd just ask. The Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "shiftedr_admin", "", "shiftedr_whosthedeeusers");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="INSERT INTO Users2 (fullname, Email, Password, Gender)
VALUES
('$_POST[fullname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]', '$_POST[gender]')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and my HTML source is

```
<form method="post" name="accountcreation" id="accountcreation" action="insertnewaccounts.php" style="background-color:#CCFFFF;">
    <center><h1 style="position:relative;left:0px;"> Account Creation </h1>

        <table>
        <tr>
        <td align="right"> Full Name: </td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="fullname nameerror"  name="fullname" min="4" class="spacing" placeholder="Your Full Name"/> </td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right">Email</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="email" name="email"  min="5" placeholder="@" />        </td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right"> Password </td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="Password" name="password"  class="spacing" placeholder="Minimum 6 Characters"/>         </td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right"> Confirm Password </td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" id="confirmpassword passworderror" class="spacing" name="pwc" placeholder="Confirm Password"/></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right"> Owner's' Gender: </td>
        <td align="left"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female </td></tr>
        </table>
        </dl>
<input type="submit" value="Check" /></center>
</form>
```

Thanks guys! I am very grateful for the help!
-Pat

Comment: Your code seems correct (with the exception of a few minor HTML errors...e.g. `</dl>` with no opening tag).  I'd be curious as to what `$_POST[gender]` returns.  Maybe throw this in: `echo "1 record added: $_POST[gender]";`.  It should return the value of the selected radio button (if one is selected).

Comment: The PHP code should bring the value of the selected radio button. Your HTML code for the radio inputs is almost perfect, you are missing a `/` at the end `>`. I believe that your issue is that you aren't using `isset($_POST['submit'])` command to handle the form.

Comment: Zigdawg, I did that. It just says "1 record added "On""

Comment: I think KarelG is right - I'm pretty sure of it. Just not sure where to put the isset or how to to revamp my code around that.